# WordPress child theme files in subdirectory not overriding

Tags: php, wordpress, include, themes, wordpress-theming

I am modifying a WordPress theme using a child theme. In my child theme folder, I have created a folder called "includes" (just like the parent) and have made edits to the content-post.php, content-single.php and content-single-portfolio.php files. I have added to the functions.php file in the child folder:

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'includes/content-post.php' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'includes/content-single.php' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . 'includes/content-single-portfolio.php' );
```

This causes a 500 internal error and I'm not sure why.

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

http://systemspecialist.net/2013/04/16/add-customized-files-includes-folder-to-wordpress-child-theme/

I also tried this solution and get the same 500 error: 
[WordPress Child Theme including includes files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128283/wordpress-child-theme-including-includes-files)

Comment: What if you forgo the require_onces and move the templates out of includes into the folder above?

Answer (score 0):

> [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)
>
> Returns an absolute server path (eg:
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme), not a URI.

your code probably converted to absolute url like

`/home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_themeincludes/content-single-portfolio.php`

get_stylesheet_directory() should always be followed by forward slash

`require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/content-post.php' );`

Your best option is to check the error log, Most 500 error message are related to php timeout, specially if the site was previously working fine before you did any php modification.

You can also try doing something like this one by one for each file

```
//Checking if file exist
if ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/content-post.php') ) {
    //Require file if it exist, 
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/content-post.php' )
} else {
    /* Echo something if file doesn't exist, if the message wasn't displayed and you still get 500 error then there's some wrong on the php file above*/
    _e('File not found');
}
```

Comment: Sorry. That was my mistake in typing the code. I still get a 500 server error.

Comment: try checking log file, I edited answer for suggestion

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Am I putting the code above in the child functions.php file?